# Encrypt HTTP Post request in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json, http-post, aes

I have an HTML page which is sending an HTTP post request to a third party application. Now that application has enabled encryption/decryption and I have to encrypt the POST request using AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING.
Can someone help me with the approach on how this can be implemented in an HTML file.

Comment: Putting that in HTML / client-side JS will expose the API keys etc. You need to do this on the server.

Comment: @ChrisG I am really a noob with javascript/html technologies. Any heads up on how to implement this on server side.

Comment: @Vishal5364 It's best to pull in a trusted and maintained node.js package that handles the encryption for you. You'll probably have to POST to your server with relevant data, encrypt, and then have your server make an http request to the third party application.

Comment: What are you using as backend?